# Arrays, creating 3rd array for count++

Tags: java, arrays, counter

I have 2 parallel arrays with values already given. One is short[marks] and the other String[names]. And I want to compare values from both so I can print out how many times a student has received a particular grade over the years. Values are already defined and given. So if: Sophie has received 85/100, 5 times in one year. I want it to print:

```
       Sophie : *****
```

I know this is what I have to do:

```
Use an array, such that the 100th index corresponds to the grade 100, the 99th
index corresponds to the grade 99, etc. This way if somebody gets a grade g you 
can just increment the gth element of the array.
```

I cannot use classes for this assignment.

can anyone help me get started?

Comment: Where is the year over year data?

Comment: in short, already given. cant change it @galuano1

Comment: havnt been taught map @AchintyaJha

Comment: now you are asking question without complete information, and crowdsourcing your homework. not good.

Comment: What is the 5 '*' meaning? And how do you determine the number 5?

Comment: not outsourcing my homwwork, i just need help getting started. There is nothing in my textbook and we were never taught this. @galuano1

Comment: sorry, 5 is the times Sophie has gotten 85, and " * " are meant to printed out as per the number of times the mark @xcoder

Comment: Pattern "Sophie : *****" does not cover the actual grade. Sophie may have grade of 85, 80, 70 etc multiple number of times. Are you given a particular grade as input to operate on it, or you need to print this pattern for all the similar grades?

Comment: she has recieved 85, 5 times so hence ***** @Kal

Comment: So, you mean the element in String[names] can be repeated i.e. Sophie appeared at least 5 times in this case??

Comment: yes thats correct so for example (this is just for sophie) short[85,85,85,85,85,98] and String[Sophie, Sophie, Sophie, Sophie, Sophie, Mark] @xcoder

Comment: May I ask how many different names are there? Is the data size large?

Comment: all together, 93 names, thats why i didnt paste it 2 @xcoder

Comment: it's not clear to me if the 85 is an input, or whether you want to print this for every grade between 0 and 100...

Comment: let me clear it up, 85 (marks) has already been given, so have the names (String[]). There is no input. I have to print the no.of times a person has received a certain mark, in this case, Sophie got 5, 85's. therefore i want to print " * " for the 5. * * * * *. @JoeriHendrickx

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to build from both arrays, marks and names, generic pairs `<name, mark>`. Then you just have to count the number of identical pairs you have per `name` to obtain the number of `*`

Hope it helps!

Comment: do i create another array for this? or is it some sort of loop?

Comment: You can build a class Pair<String,Short> representing a pair of name + grade. Assuming that you have 100 entries in both arrays you will end up with 100 initial pairs (in an ArrayList for example). the next step will be to extract IDENTICAL (same name and grade)pairs from that set.

Comment: cant use classes for this assignment, thats why its so hard :( @lahniep

Answer (score 0):

ok...for the sake of this weird assignment, let's do something weird (I dunno if this will work)...and actually bad coding and performance as well maybe...anyway...

Now we have 2 arrays: name and marks. Say, for example, we have ["A", "B", "A", "A"] for names and [80,100,80,70] for marks.

```
1) Loop through names and if you do not find, say "-1", set a temp var called, say, candidate to store the person i.e. "A" at first.
2) Get the corresponding mark from marks[]
3) Replace name with the cast-ed mark => names["80", "B", "A", "A"]
4) Keep looping names and repeat the above if the name = candidate 
5) At the end, you have names["80", "B", "80", "70"]
6)Loop through it and Make two temp var, say, count and target to record the first mark not equals "-1" and not containing any character i.e A-Z
7) count is used to keep the count of the target. So, target="80" and count = 2 in the 1st loop.
8) Set the element to "-1" when you have accessed it.
9) Print candidate, target and count <-- do the * thing
10) names become ["-1", "B", "-1", "70"]
11) repeat everything
12) The idea is like names[] will go like:  ["A", "B", "A", "A"] => ["80", "B", "80", "70"] => ["-1", "B", "-1", "70"] => ["-1", "B", "-1", "-1"] => ["-1", "100", "-1", "-1"] => ["-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"]
```

I probably miss out a few steps but this is the rough idea and I hope you understand it. It is probably better to have a 3rd array instead of replacing names[], well, decide yourself. As a whole, it might take 3-4 nested loops (I can;t imagine this...=.=)

Comment: its not like i know how to create a 3rd array, kinda stuck between a rock and a hard place

Comment: yeh i will, i'll try it tomorrow, 2 am here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you can't use classes...
Not sure if you meant your own classes or any java classes (except for extreme basics like String...) So I'm assuming worst case.

Your inputs are:

- `String[] names` containing a bunch of names
- `int[] marks` containing a bunch of marks (corresponding to the names of the corresponding indices
- `int markToFind` the mark for which you want to find the occurences

Your outputs are :

- `String[] uniqueNames` containing the names again, but uniquely
- `int[] markOccurences` containing for each name the occurences (with corresponding indices to the previous array)

**Algorithm** (pseudo java, you can fix it yourself)

```
{

  String[] uniqueNames = new String[names.length]; // this is oversized, which we can live with.  Counting uniques without a Set is annoying
  int[] markOccurences = new int[uniqueNames.length]; // will default to 0 everywhere

  for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    int nameIdx = addUnique(uniqueNames, names[i]);
    if (marks[i] == markToFind) markOccurences[nameIdx]++;
  }

  // print asterisks per name (insert your code here)
}

int addUnique(String[] array, String element){
  int idx = indexOf(array, element);
  if (idx<0){
    idx = indexOf(array, null);
    array[idx] = element;
  }
  return id;
}

int indexOf(String[] haystack, String needle){
 // implement naively
}

}
```

Not that this would be a LOT easier with classes.  What a strange assignment

Comment: thanks, i'll give that a go! i think out tutor just wants us to learn how to write proper java code before we start getting into object oriented java, setting the foundations i guess

Comment: @user2278109 I just noticed I left a subtle bug in there for you to find ;) corrected.

Comment: yeah...i get what you are trying to code, but i coudnt get it working, thanks anyway!